# Automatic high torque swinger from a motor or a spare CD drive

Tags: motor, driver

An idea that comes to my mind to swing a baby swing automatically is using a CD drive eject - close function , I have several such drives I dont use and I dont want to use a computer to  do the periodic control eject \ close. Can I attach an auxiliary circuit which just helps in periodic open-close motion of the CD drive. Also, are there any other ways to make the swing automatic , what I need is just a backforth motion to couple it with the swing?

The major requirement is high torque high amplitude swinging which the modern fisherprice swings lack and babies love.

weight : should withstand 1 to 12 Kg babies

Could be used with any normal swing to convert it to auto swinging with all safety aspects fulfilled.

Here is the typical swing:

[image]

Note: Some babies wont just sleep unless they are swinged continuously hence the question.

Note : CD room requirement is no longer valid.

Comment: A cd drive ejector stalls easily. It does not have the strength to move a steady hand, let alone a baby.

Comment: @Passerby suspension of baby on the swing is the key

Comment: \*thinks of Rube Goldberg\*

Answer (score 4):

Well, you probably can. Simply create some very slow generator (based on 555) and connect some relay in parallel with the eject button of the CD drive.

But isn't usual CD drives too noisy for such application? And how long the drive mechanic will live with such big mechanical loads?

Instead of using CD Drive, some small motor with gearbox seems to be a better solution for me. The motor need to have 20..30..50rpm output speed. [Some of these](http://www.servocity.com/html/3-12v_gear_motors.html) may fit, but there are thousands of them in the on-line shops.

The needed speed depends on what the baby prefer.

Just put a disk on the output shaft and tiе a rubber band at the disk periphery. The other end of the band tie to the baby swing. In this construction only ON/OFF and optionally motor speed control is needed. The swinging will be generated by the mechanic. Here is very raw drawing of what I mean:

[image]

Very small motor is needed, because the swing will be accelerated smooth in the time. Some adjustment of the motor speed might be needed in order to work in the resonance frequency of the swing. Count the swings per minute of the swing and search for the same rpm motor. Some variable voltage power source will make such adjustments easy.

---

### Safety:

The maximal amplitude of the swing must be limited in some way. If because of some reason, the elastic band is winded on the shaft, something must stop the swing and cause the band to be broken or the motor stalled, but not the swing torn down. Make the extended tests without your baby in the swing, but some heavy enough object instead.

Comment: Also, are there any other ways to make the swing automatic , what I need is just a backforth motion to couple it with the swing?

Comment: If you are seeking clarification or commenting on the question, that belongs as a comment post on the question. If you are answering the OP's question, then "some very slow generator" and the general hand-waving is a really poor example of an answer.

Comment: @AnindoGhosh - I don't need clarification. The question is clear and my answer is about how to implement what the elex101 wants. "very slow generator" is because the needed frequency may varies with the baby - some like it slow, some faster.

Comment: I'm sorry, but "some generator" and "some relay" isn't even an answer, it's "some vague words".

Comment: @AnindoGhosh - Internet is full of 555 schematics. If you can't search in it - it is not my problem.

Comment: Wow, why the hate for John's answer - a small cheap motor with an arm is by far the most elegant solution to this. My suggestion would be the rear wiper motor from a car, they are quiet, reliable, powerful, low-voltage, and they have a reciprocating action ready made.

Comment: @JohnU - Thanks for defending me! IMO, the car wipers motor will be far more powerful than needed for this application.

Comment: @johnfound My downvote is for the vague hand-waving in the first paragraph.

Comment: @johnfound thanks for the idea, but can you  elaborate with a schematic of the apparatus to achieve this. Your description seems vague as I cant understand how the rotating servo motor will help in back and forth motion. Also please mention where to couple the motor output ?

Comment: @johnfound you can use http://www.digikey.com/schemeit to explain your idea clearly

Comment: @johnfound +1 this is an good solution , specially using elastic band instead of a string. But will the motor able to handle the weight and opposite forces due to rubber band? Also is a servo motor required for this or a simple DC motor would do? for a 6 kg weight can you suggest the motor specification?

Comment: @elex101 look at this page http://robokits.co.in/shop/index.php?main_page=index&cPath=2 they have so many motors with different RPM and TORQUE do get a motor with rpm around 30 to 50 and thereafter you can control the rpm by using a simple IC555 based speed controller

Comment: @elex101 you could use ac motors such used in sewing machines or mixer grinder.but these require some speed controllers like TRIAC based or Wire wound resistor based; but i don't recommend you to use ac motors.DC motors have a mechanical gear to reduce the speed of the motor and to increase the torque even if the gear fails the motor would stall and wont create much problem in compare with ac motors.whats your view about this

Comment: @elex101 - I fully described my ideas on this subject. I, personally would not use ceiling fan for this task. There are so many cheap, more suitable devices around.

Comment: @johnfound can you recommend an exact device from http://robokits.co.in/shop/index.php?main_page=index&cPath=2

Comment: @elex101 - I would try [this one](http://robokits.co.in/shop/index.php?main_page=product_info&cPath=2&products_id=377), but it seems to be a little bit slow. You understand that it is a guess, right?

Comment: updated the question and added bounty,

Answer (score 2):

The baby swing is a pendulum which will have a natural frequency of oscillation only dependent on the distance from the centre of rotation to the centre of gravity of the baby and carrier. This may vary with baby's position. If the swing is nudged at the correct frequency the oscillations will increase in amplitude until friction counters the applied force.

I suggest a variable speed motor and gearbox with an eccentric pusher to nudge the rope every cycle. Once the swing reaches a certain oscillation amplitude the pusher will lose contact so it's self-limiting. To set up, push the swing and measure it's natural frequency of oscillation. Set the motor speed to match.

[image]

Comment: Nice idea , can you link to some practical motor

Comment: Also how can it be setup for the swing shown in the question. Will this give high amplitude swing ?

Comment: @elex101: Looking at my sketch, you can set the amplitude by 1) moving the motor-gearbox closer to the rope pivot for a larger amplitude, etc., or 2) move the pusher further from the gearbox centre for the same result. If the system works you will initially see a bend in the rope as sketched but when swinging gets going it should, ideally, form a straight-line tangent to the pusher.

Comment: @elex101: You could start off by trying to source a car wiper or window winder motor assembly and a variable voltage DC power supply 0 - 12 V at 1 - 2 A might be enough.

Comment: @elex101: If you find a fixed speed motor / power supply close to what you require you could adjust the length of the swing ropes to match the actuator and swing. See Wikipedia's pendulum article for a formula.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Arduino, and use the code from this site:

http://singlevalve.web.fc2.com/Atapiduino/atapiduino.htm

Make a loop that will keep sending the eject/close command.

Comment: thanks but I dont want to invest in using arduino or any controller, I believe this can be accomplished by a simple circuit.

Comment: Well, you can hack the CDROM eject button, if you want to. Solder a wire to the button, then connect the wire to relay. Use 555 timer with small "on" time, each time the "on" is triggered, your relay will connect, and will simulate the pressing of the button

Comment: -1 for unnecessary & gratuitous arduino usage.

Comment: @JohnU, the poster did not mention that he did not want to use Arduino, so suggesting using Arduino is one of the possible answer. He is free to accept or not the answer. Thanks.

Comment: I never said it wasn't what the OP wanted, I said it was a poor solution and voted accordingly. Isn't that what this system is about?

Comment: @JohnU your comment clearly shows you dinged the post because of Arduino usage. The solution itself is not practical so I will not upvote it, I don't believe a CD ROM eject motor can move the weight of an average-sized plump baby, regardless of what circuitry drives it. And no, this site is not about downvoting anything Arduino.

Comment: He could've suggested any micro or other convoluted control system and I would've downvoted it for the same reason, this problem is solvable with a very basic motor & mechanical linkage with no special control whatsoever.

Comment: @JohnU I'm curious: How would a motor and mechanical linkage be kept synchronized with the period of oscillation of the swing? Given that the swing's natural period will vary with distance from fulcrum to center of mass, and will therefore change due to center of mass shifting over time as the baby grows heavier or is swaddled with more clothes etc.

Comment: User adjustment. It's not rocket surgery, and there's better things to spend hours of one's life writing control algorithms for.

Answer (score 1):

In order to respond to your update,
an option with a simple circuit that opens and closes the drive periodically can easily be made by a switch reversing the polarity of the current fed to the motor. You can see a good explanation for this in the following youtube video for example, where someone presents how to make a crawlworm bot from a CD drive:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pKIG4uJBIsQ

Depending on your swing, you can easily attach it to one of the legs at a height corresponding to the amplitude you want the baby to swing at.

There are two drawbacks for this approach:
 1. as stated by other users before, the motor will most likely not be strong enough (you can block a CD drive opening with your hand easily)
 2. this setup only allows to open at close at a single frequency, given by the motors speed. You could adjust voltages to tune this, but I am not sure to which extend this works out.

Good luck

/edit:
A combination of this approach and the elastic band option might be powerful enough in time to get a swinging motion going. Don't forget to limit the motion, though.